# Meaning of "write a song"

Tags: translation

Does the verb *to write* as used in "*write a song*" refer to only the lyrics (words) or does/can it include the composition of music?

Comment: Depends.  How precise are you writing and what is your audience?

Comment: I'm not writing anything, I just read this in a book. There is no context, it is just a side character (we don't know anything about him) that says he wrote a song. So the answer is that it depends then?

Comment: Good question! The simple meaning of 'writing a song' is lyrics only, (as in, we have no reason or information to infer composition also) but where somebody is credited as 'songwriter' on a music album,  etc it seems to imply composition of the musical piece as well.

Comment: It could be any of the three (music, lyrics or both). Without any further context, I would assume both.

Comment: @EnglishStudent "*The simple meaning of 'writing a song' is lyrics only*" I don't think so. Have a look at the definition of *songwriter*.

Comment: @EnglishStudent - I believe that _writing a song_ would imply writing the music more so (or at least as much as) writing lyrics.  Some songs have no lyrics.  One might argue that lyrics without music would be poetry, but then you're getting into the discussion of whether rap is music and you have to bring up [John Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Cage) and it gets all philosophical and we really just want to hear some tunes.  Anyway, I think writing a song could mean lyrics, music, or both but, in the absence of any other information, I would assume it includes writing the music.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for the clarification. Please read my explanatory comment here addressed to Roger Sinasohn and yourself. The confusion arises from a cultural difference.

Comment: @Roger Sinasohn and michael.hor257k thanks a lot for the clarification. The confusion arises due to a cultural difference. HERE IN INDIA, the music field has undergone extreme specialisation in that one person 'writes the song' (lyrics -- it is different from poetry in being specifically meant to be composed as song) another 'composes it' -- this person is called 'music director' -- and yet another person sings it! We have singer-composers but the singer or composer is very unlikely to **write the song**. In Europe/ USA 'songwriter' evidently carries the meaning of both lyrics and composition.

Comment: Yes, in the US, modern songwriters tend to do both music and lyrics.  As if that weren't bad enough, there are _singer-songwriters_ who not only write both the music and lyrics, but also perform it.